# R: Implement while loop to stop when results don't change value anymore

Tags: r

I'm currently working on an R script for the c-mean clustering method. I started with a rather simple version, to get the basic structure done. The idea is to cluster the values into n classes.

I have a vector of 8 values and I pick two  to be my first candidates.

```
values <- c(4,8,12,5,9,30,75,13)
candidates <- c(values[1],values[6])
```

Then the elements of "values" shall be sorted for their distance from the candidates. I'm not sure if my version is the most elegant one but it seems to be working.

If the distance from one element to candidate one is smaller, it shall be sorted in group.1,  and the other way around. In each case, the group that the value is not a part of, gets an NA.

After going through all the elements of "values" the mean value of each group is calculated and the process is repeated. In this case 10 times, because I added the loop.

The idea is, in the end you get the same values over and over again. Those values are the centers of the cluster.

```
group.2 <- 0
group.1 <- 0
for(j in 1:10){
    for(i in 1:length(values)){
    if( abs(candidates[1]-values[i]) < abs(candidates[2]-values[i]) ){
    group.2[i] <- -999
    group.1[i] <- values[i]
} else if( abs(candidates[1]-values[i]) > abs(candidates[2]-values[i]) ) {
group.1[i] <- -999
group.2[i] <- values[i]
} 
}
group.1 <- group.1[!group.1==-999]
group.2 <- group.2[!group.2==-999]

candidates<- c(mean(group.1), mean(group.2))
print(candidates)
}
```

If you look at the output, you'll see that you actually get the final centers of the clusters after the second repetition.

What I can't figure out is how to make the loop stop, as soon as the results aren't changing anymore.

My idea is to add another loop which terminates the process as soon as

```
candidates[j]==candidates[j-1]
```

however I can't figure out how to access the previous value j-1 of the loop.

Comment: R supports `NA` values. There is no reason for using `-999` as a substitute.

Comment: I actually tried exchanging the -999 with NA and as a result it sets every resulting value as NA.. I think I'll just keep the -999.

Comment: No, get rid of bad habits. You only need to know that `x==NA` is never `TRUE`, but `is.na(x)` is `TRUE` if `x` is an `NA` value.

Comment: Do you maybe have a link explaining that further? I'm not sure I understand what you mean and I get the error

`Error in if (abs(candidates[1] - values[i]) < abs(candidates[2] - values[i])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Change `group.1 <- group.1[!group.1==-999]` to `group.1 <- na.omit(group.1)`. However, you don't need these `NA` values at all, if you use a vectorized approach instead of the inner `for` loop like I show in my answer.

Comment: Okay I just tried your version and I think I even understand how it works! I hope I understand it well enough to use it for more than one dimension. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new variable, say `old.candidates` at the beginning of the loop that is set equal to `candidates`.  Then, after setting `candidates`, check equality and break if they are equal.

```
candidates <- 0  # You have to initialize it here
for(j in 1:10){
  old <- candidates
  # Do stuff
  candidates <- c(mean(group.1), mean(group.2))
  if(old - candidates == 0) break()
}
```

A better way would be to check if `abs(old - candidates) < tol` for some small value of `tol`.

Comment: That worked right away! Thanks a lot!
I actually had to expand the condition for each candidate, because there's more then one value but beside that, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Better use vectorization and write a function:

```
values <- c(4,8,12,5,9,30,75,13)
candidates <- c(values[1],values[6])

cmeans <- function(values, candidates, maxiter=10, tol = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5, verbose=TRUE) {

  for (j in seq_len(maxiter)) {
    divide <- abs(candidates[1]-values) <= abs(candidates[2]-values)
    group.1 <- values[divide]
    group.2 <- values[!divide]
    candidates.new<- c(mean(group.1), mean(group.2))
    if (min(abs(candidates.new-candidates)) < tol) {
      return(candidates.new)
    } else {
      if (verbose) message(paste(candidates.new, collapse=", "))  
      candidates <- candidates.new
    }
  }
}

cmeans(values, candidates)
#8.5, 52.5
#11.5714285714286, 75
#[1] 11.57143 75.00000
```

Comment: This looks really professional, thanks! Also it's way beyond what I'm capable of in R so far :D

Comment: @ukues It should also be much faster than your solution. The important part is that you don't need the inner `for` loop.